# Images stopped showing in cs-cart site

Tags: php, .htaccess, cs-cart

I have below .htaccess code in images folder of my cs-cart site:

```
PElmTW9kdWxlIG1vZF9zZWN1cml0eS5jPg0KU2VjRmlsdGVyRW5naW5lIE9mZg0KPC9JZk1vZHVsZT4 | base64 -d
```

what is the use of this .htaccess code.
when checked server error log it is showing below error

`/var/www/html/mysite/images/.htaccess: Invalid command 'PElmTW9kdWxlIG1vZF9zZWN1cml0eS5                                    jPg0KU2VjRmlsdGVyRW5naW5lIE9mZg0KPC9JZk1vZHVsZT4'`

perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

I got to know the reason for this error, Somebody through scripting created .htaccess file in images folder of our site which is a big threat.
We are now changing the folder permissions, but is there any other way to handle this kind of threats?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the result of a recent vulnerability in the CS-Cart product.

The recent message sent to CS-Cart Customers.

> Publish date: May 26, 2014
>   Affected versions: 2.x.x, 3.0.x, 4.0.x, 4.1.1 to 4.1.2
>   Vulnerability type: Arbitrary code execution
>   Severity: Critical
>
> Summary
>
> The update fixes a vulnerability that can result in a remote unauthenticated attacker executing arbitrary script in the context of the end-user's browser session.
>
> Check if your site was affected
>
> Check if the following files exist in the CS-Cart directory on your server:
>   js/thumbs.php
>   images/test.gif
>
> If these files exist, immediately remove them.
>
> We also recommend to check your server for new unknown files and unauthorized file changes.
>
> Solution
>
> Follow the instructions for your CS-Cart or Multi-Vendor version:
>
> 1) In CS-Cart 4.0.x, 4.1.1 to 4.1.2 and Multi-Vendor 4.0.x, 4.1.1 to 4.1.2:
>       a) Delete the file app/payments/atos.php
>       b) Delete the directory app/payments/atos_files
>       c) Delete the file app/payments/hsbc.php
>       d) Delete the directory app/payments/hsbc_files
>
> 2) In CS-Cart 2.x.x and 3.0.x (all editions)
>       a) Delete the file payments/atos.php
>       b) Delete the directory payments/atos_files
>       c) Delete the file payments/hsbc.php
>       d) Delete the directory payments/hsbc_files

Comment: Thanks for reply. We checked the file on our server atos.php but these files modified date is very old, also not sure if this file is important for cs-cart. So is it necessery to delete. we have found and deleted thumbs.php and test.gif files.